# Select from one table if present,else select from another having latest date

Tags: sql, oracle

There are Three tables T1 and T2 and T3

T3 stores person details
T1 stores primary phone number of person,
T2 stores non primary phone number of persons.

T1

| Personid | Primaryphone | dateload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 02/08/21 |
| 2 | 1002 | 03/07/21 |
| 4 | 1004 | 04/08/20 |
| 5 | 1005 | 08/09/20 |

T2

| Personid | NonPrimphone | dateload |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1011 | 12/03/21 |
| 3 | 1003 | 20/02/21 |
| 4 | 1024 | 30/12/21 |
| 6 | 1006 | 08/08/20 |
| 3 | 1007 | 04/04/21 |
| 3 | 1008 | 21/08/21 |

T3

| Per_numb | person_id |
| --- | --- |
| 501 | 1 |
| 502 | 2 |
| 503 | 3 |
| 504 | 4 |
| 505 | 5 |
| 506 | 6 |

What i want is, select all personumber from T3 and thier phone number , the criteria is , if the person is having primary phone number select that, if not having primary phone number select phone number from non primary table having latest dateload.

i.e

O/p

| Per_numb | phonenumber |
| --- | --- |
| 501 | 1001 |
| 502 | 1002 |
| 503 | 1008 |
| 504 | 1004 |
| 505 | 1005 |
| 506 | 1006 |

I also want to join these three tables and not use sub queries as the sub query is making the execution slow.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked into LEFT JOINS and CASE statements for what field to select from what table?

Comment: I have tried joining the tableT3 with T1 and T2, and using case but the problem is on joining T1 and T2 , if a person is having both primary and non primary phone, i am getting both phone numbers.what i want is when phone number from T1 is selected it should not look in T2.also in my case all these tables have lakhs of rows so my performance is very much compromised.

Comment: "as the subquery is making the execution slow"? Where did you get that idea? How much do you know about how the Oracle optimizer works? If you have subqueries in your query and the optimizer thinks joins would be better, the optimizer will apply that optimization itself, it doesn't need your help (certainly not in a simple query like yours)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `coalesce()`:

```
select t3.*,
       coalesce( (select t1.primaryphone
                  from t1
                  where t1.personid = t3.personid
                 ),
                 (select t2.phone
                  from t2
                  where t2.personid = t3.personid
                  order by t2.dateload desc
                  fetch first 1 row only
                 )
               ) a_good_phone
from t3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct Per_numb , coalesce(Primaryphone,NonPrimphone)
from table3 t3
left join table1 t1 
  on t1.Personid = t3.Personid
outer apply (
select * from table2 t2
where t2.personid = t3,personid
order by dateload desc 
limit 1
) t2
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the query below is optimal, or close to optimal. Instead of speculating on what will or will not make the query "fast" or "slow", test it on your actual data.

Note about consistency: the "same" column is called `personid` in two tables, but `person_id` in the third (with an underscore). This kind of inconsistency will drive your developers nuts. Can you have that fixed?

```
select t3.per_numb, sq.phone
from   t3 left outer join
       (
         select  personid, primaryphone as phone
           from  t1
         union all
         select  personid, nonprimphone
           from  t2
           where (personid, dateload) in
                 ( select personid, max(dateload)
                   from   t2
                   where  personid not in (select personid from t1)
                   group  by personid
                 )
       ) sq on t3.person_id = sq.personid
order  by per_numb    --  if needed
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to get the latest `NonPrimphone` and `COALESCE()` to pick the number from `T1` or `T2`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t3.Per_numb,
       COALESCE(
         t1.Primaryphone,
         FIRST_VALUE(t2.NonPrimphone) OVER (PARTITION BY t3.person_id ORDER BY t2.dateload DESC) 
       ) phonenumber
FROM Table3 t3 
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.Personid = t3.person_id
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Personid = t3.person_id
ORDER BY t3.Per_numb;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c0717f83d2e3a5abc822569bddcdb559).